# SwiftUI | How to use share sheet to copy localized strings?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios-sharesheet

I added share sheet button and it works great for my English texts (copying ,sharing)  BUT for the localized texts the app hung  and crash when I add `LocalizedStringKeys()` , and when I don't add it the text is showing English.

```
 func shareSheet(){
    isShareSheetShowing.toggle()
    let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [LocalizedStringKey(quote)], applicationActivities: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly `NSLocalizedString`

```
func shareSheet(){
   isShareSheetShowing.toggle()
   let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [NSLocalizedString(quote, comment: "")], applicationActivities: nil) //<--Here
   UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```